# Location name from SQL Server and plot on Leaflet map

Tags: jquery, laravel, leaflet

When I tried  to plot latitude and longitude in the map, it returns

> leaflet.js:5 Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)

```
var obj =[{"lon":"27.748936","lat":"85.318788"},{"lon":"28\u00b0 02' 06.32","lat":"82\u00b0 28' 54.74"},{"lon":"83\u00b027'51.15","lat":"27\u00b042'28.5"},{"lon":"28\u00b002'06.1","lat":"082\u00b028'54.1"},{"lon":" 83\u00b027'7.00","lat":" 27\u00b030'21.02"},{"lon":"83\u00b027'51.15","lat":"27\u00b042'28.5"},{"lon":"87\u00b0 42' 12.83","lat":"26\u00b0 40' 10.11"},{"lon":"87\u00b0 42' 12.83","lat":"26\u00b0 40' 10.11"},{"lon":"N 27\u00b030'21.6","lat":"E 083\u00b027'06.6"},{"lon":"80.5794","lat":"29.3008"},{"lon":" 87\u00b042'13.92","lat":" 26\u00b040'11.44"},},{"lon":null,"lat":null},{"lon":null,"lat":null},{"lon":null,"lat":null},{"lon":null,"lat":null}]
console.log(obj);




var map = L.map('map').setView([28.41752832637288,84.13003176934866], 13);

var countrieslayer=L.geoJson(nepal).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(countrieslayer.getBounds());
L.geoJson(obj.lat,obj.lon).addTo(map);


var marker = L.marker([obj]).addTo(map);
// var point=[27.6493, 85.3059];
// var marker=L.marker(point).addTo(map);
// L.geoJSON(sites, {
//     // style: myStyle
// }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: For building GeoJSON you will need the place's coordinates too. Depending how you fetch the SQL data, you might be able to build a GeoJSON right away and place it in the `address` variable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON#Example

Comment: Is it compulsory to put coordinates also manually? I  have many location name in my database but no coordinates. Is there any method to get coordinates automatically by fetching the name of location  from database?

Comment: Yes that is called "geocoding". It's not that easy to do yourself, there are a few services available (free and paid) from different vendors, Google, Mapbox, OpenStreetMap/Nominatim...

Comment: I add latitude and longitude in tables and display in javascript . When i tried to add in map it returns leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined.

Comment: Can you update the code in your post with what you just tried? I will answer later

Answer (score 2):

I took the list of place names from your first (unedited) post and wrote a Python script with the [Geocoder library](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder) that would fetch coordinates from OpenStreetMap.

I had to make some adjustments, some places couldn't be found initially, I think that's because you can only really search them by their English names (or maybe there were some typos). So I changed these:

```
Bheemdatta - Bhimdatta
Dasharathchand - Dasharathchanda
Kirt - (I haven't found this place?)
Saphebagar - Sanfebagar
```

The geocoder script goes through each address, and then saves the results to "results.geojson"

```py
import json
import geocoder
import time

places = ["Amargadhi","Banepa","Bhaktapur","... etc ..."]

# stub for building the GeoJSON    
geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": []
}

for place in places:
    g = geocoder.osm('{} Nepal'.format(place)) # search for e.g. "Amargadhi Nepal"
    print place, g.latlng

    # create a point feature for the GeoJSON structure
    pointfeature = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [g.lng, g.lat]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": place,
            "address": g.address,
        }
    }

    # if there's a result, add it to the GeoJSON FeatureCollection
    if g.latlng:
        geojson["features"].append(pointfeature)

    time.sleep(1) # wait 1 second

print "Saving to results.geojson"

with open("results.geojson","w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(geojson, indent=2))
    f.close()
```

You can then use the resulting GeoJSON in your Leaflet map:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([28.41752832637288,84.13003176934866], 10);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var obj = nepaldata; // replace "nepaldata" and insert GeoJSON here
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(obj);
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  console.log(layer);
    layer.bindPopup("<b>"+ layer.feature.properties.name +"</b><br/><br/>"+ layer.feature.properties.address);
});
map.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());
```

You can see a [working demo on Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/55lH6nZlIVuWdCaK3CtR?p=preview). I also put the full list of places and coordinates there (see nepal.js file).

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. But when I put coordinates statically, its working.